# NATS Streaming Server being shutdown while using cluster

Tags: nats.io, nats-streaming-server

I have Nats Streaming server running on 3 VMs and they are clustered following the official NATS docs tutorial. Every time there is as change on the files one instance gets shutdown then all the others shut down a few moments later.

Tried changing some configuration file but without success

```
# NATS specific configuration
port: 4222
cluster {
  listen: 0.0.0.0:6222
  routes: ["nats://VM-1-IP:6222", "nats://VM-2-IP:6222"]
}

# NATS Streaming specific configuration
streaming {
  id: mycluster
  store: file
  dir: store
  cluster {
    node_id: "a"
    peers: ["b", "c"]
    bootstrap: true
    sync: true
#    log_path: store
    raft_election_timeout: "2s"
    raft_lease_timeout: "2s"

  }
}
```

E.g.: Somebody publishes by connecting on VM-1, VM-1 gets the messages... A few moments later (probably when storing the messages) I get this error on one instance, then the same appears on the others.

```
VM-0 Terminal

[10913] 2019/07/18 16:25:43.753835 [INF] VM-0-IP:60063 - rid:12 - Router connection closed
[10913] 2019/07/18 16:25:43.754294 [ERR] VM-0-IP:60063 - rid:12 - attempted to connect to route port
panic: interface conversion: stores.SubStore is *stores.RaftSubStore, not *stores.FileSubStore

goroutine 1477 [running]:
github.com/nats-io/nats-streaming-server/stores.(*FileStore).autoSync(0xc00011e600)
    /home/envoy-dns/go/src/github.com/nats-io/nats-streaming-server/stores/filestore.go:1329 +0x33c
created by time.goFunc
    /usr/local/go/src/time/sleep.go:169 +0x44
exit status 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response. This was a bug in master but not in any public release. A fix was made back in July: https://github.com/nats-io/nats-streaming-server/pull/886